# Visual Studio Extensibility, Programmatically Creating A Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extensibility

I am attempting to programmatically add a test project to a solution. However when the code below executes I receive a File IO exception on the line "vhaSolution.GetProjectTemplate("TestProject.zip", "Csharp")". The error indicates that "he language specified is not supported by any of the installed packages". Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

```
   public enum TestProjectType
    {
        Unit,
        Acceptance,
        Integration
    }

 public static void CreateTestProject(string fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName,string projectName,TestProjectType testProjectType)
        {
            #region Argument Validation
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName.Trim()))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName", "The solution file location is required.");
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectName.Trim()))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("projectName", "The project name is required.");
            }

            if (!File.Exists(fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The file {0} specified does not exist.", fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName));
            }

            if (testProjectType == null) testProjectType = TestProjectType.Unit;
            #endregion

            System.Type vsType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.8.0");
            Object vs = System.Activator.CreateInstance(vsType, true);
            EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte8Obj = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)vs;

            Solution2 vhaSolution = (Solution2)dte8Obj.Solution;
            vhaSolution.Open(fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName);

            //TODO: Externalize company name
            string cmpnyName = "Vha";
            string testProjectName = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}{3}",cmpnyName,projectName,testProjectType.ToString(),"Test");
            string testTemplateLocation = vhaSolution.GetProjectTemplate("TestProject.zip", "CSharp");
            FileInfo rootSolutionFolder = new FileInfo(fullyQualifiedSolutionFileName);

            //TODO: Externalize test directory name
            string testDirName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}",rootSolutionFolder.DirectoryName,"test",testProjectType.ToString(),testProjectName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(testDirName))
            {
                //may throw an exception if the dir can't be created...
                Directory.CreateDirectory(testDirName);
            }


            Project vhaTestProj = vhaSolution.AddFromTemplate(testTemplateLocation,testDirName,testProjectName + ".proj",false);
            vhaTestProj.Save(String.Format("{0}\\{1}.proj",testDirName , testProjectName));



        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use the prog ID VisualStudio.DTE.9.0 so that it would point to the correct registry location for VS 2008.