# How to create C# project with .csproj extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, open-source, visual-studio-code

I am trying to look out for creating C# Project in Visual Studio Code with .csproj extension but unable to find anything relevant for the same.
Please share the helpful with prerequisites for the same.

Comment: I think you're asking how to create a C# project file programmatically, in which case try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790528/create-a-visual-studio-project-programmatically.  If that's not right then please comment back

Answer (score 0):

you can use Yeoman on Terminal (of VS Code or any terminal write):

```
 yo aspnet
```

then you choice what you need to create, I assume you have installed Core and Yoeman:

```
What type of application do you want to create? (Use arrow keys)
❯ Empty Web Application 
  Empty Web Application (F#) 
  Console Application 
  Console Application (F#) 
  Web Application 
  Web Application Basic [without Membership and Authorization] 
  Web Application Basic [without Membership and Authorization] (F#) 
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)
```

If you want to create Web application choose it and press ENTER answer the name you wish (test_web my example) and then push ENTER:

```
   create test_web/.gitignore
   create test_web/Program.fs
   create test_web/Startup.fs
   create test_web/test_web.fsproj
   create test_web/web.config
   create test_web/Properties/launchSettings.json
   create test_web/README.md
   create test_web/runtimeconfig.template.json
   create test_web/global.json
```

after to create the web application test_web you need execute:

```
cd test_web
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

To run from  VS Code, you only have to open the folder test_web. Debugger is recognize .Net projects then you only push F5 to run from VS Code.

To install yeoman if you dont have:

```
npm install -g yo bower
```

[web reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/yeoman)

you need [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) to use yeoman and npm.

anyway you have option to use monoDevelop in Ubuntu.

I tested it and it is working on Ubuntu for me.